# Making multiple arrays of the same size with random numbers and getting cpu time

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, average

I am trying to do the following;

1. I want to make `10` `5x5` arrays of random numbers. So far i know to make one array I just do something like `matrix5 = rand(5);` Is there an easy way to make 10 separate arrays?
2. I want to get the cpu time to make each individual array.
3. I want to get the average time to make the ten

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy:

```
matrix = zeros(5, 5, 10);
timeTotal = 0;
for i = 1:10
    tic
    matrix(:, :, i) = rand(5);
    t = toc
    timeTotal = timeTotal + t;
end
averageTime = timeTotal/10
```

Then you will get the individual times and the average time. The result will give you the final result of a 10 long array that contains `5x5` random arrays.

Comment: cs27275 wants ten arrays with size 5x5, so the first line should changed to `matrix=zeros(5, 10, 10)`. After that you must apply the followed change to your code. `matrix(i,:,:)=rand(5)` is wrong!

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi I get what you are saying, i have changed the code.

Answer (score -1):

First: You can use the following command,

```
matrix10x5x5 = rand(5, 5, 10);
```

Second: Put `tic` and `toc` at the first and end of your commands, respectively.

Third: Similar to the Second section use `tic` at the first and `toc` at the end, then compute the average time.

Comment: The OP asks for the CPU time of each array, how will you achieve this?